# jenkins parallel call for external function loaded from file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have an external function to call multiple times (with different variable values) from my jenkins pipeline and was hoping to make this call parallel.

Here's my pipeline code.

```
stepsForParallel = [:]
parallel_list = ['apple','banana','orange']
def groovyFile = load "${path}/runFruit.groovy"
for(value in parallel_list){
  stepsForParallel.put("Run for fruit-${value}", groovyFile.runForFruit(value))
}
parallel stepsForParallel
```

And my groovy file called 'runFruit' is as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def runForFruit(fruitValue){
  ..do something here..
}
return this
```

For this code the pipeline still runs sequentially.
Perhaps because in this line inside the for loop
`stepsForParallel.put("Run for fruit-${value}", groovyFile.runForFruit(value))` an actual call to the external function is being made?

Any suggestions on how to achieve this parallelization?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#parallel-execute-in-parallel) for the `parallel` step, it takes a map from branch names (the name of the parallel executions) to closures which are the code that will be executed per parallel stage. In your case you are not passing a closure, but rather executing the function itself.

```
parallel firstBranch: {
    // do something
}, secondBranch: {
    // do something else
},
failFast: true|false
```

So you need to construct your code to fit the `parallel` format by passing a closure that contains your code to execute as the map value.
In your case it will look something like (using `collectEntries`):

```
 parallel_list = ['apple','banana','orange']
 def groovyFile = load "${path}/runFruit.groovy"
 stepsForParallel = parallel_list.collectEntries{ fruit ->
     ["Run for fruit-${fruit}" : {
          groovyFile.runForFruit(fruit)
     }]
 }
 parallel stepsForParallel
```

Or if you prefer your format using the for loop:

```
stepsForParallel = [:]
parallel_list = ['apple','banana','orange']
def groovyFile = load "${path}/runFruit.groovy"
for(value in parallel_list){ 
     stepsForParallel.put("Run for fruit-${value}", { groovyFile.runForFruit(value) })
}
parallel stepsForParallel
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it in below way :

```
def fruit_list = ['apple','banana','orange']
def groovyFile
def stepsForParallel = [:]

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                script{
                      groovyFile = load "runFruit.groovy"
                        stepsForParallel = fruit_list.collectEntries {
                            ["${it}" : groovyFile.runForFruit(it)]
                        }                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
parallel stepsForParallel
```

**Output**:
[image]

Comment: You must put parallel stepsForParallel into script section